Powerbi filter R script exporting to CSV
In PowerBi I have a table like this:



Hours
Type




8
Green


6
Red



I have a R script like this:
Table <- paste0("\\\\Server\\Test\\Test.csv")

write.table(dataset, file = Table, sep = ";", na = "", row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)

But before save as CSV I want to filter it on the column "Type". What R code do I use.
I know I can filter the column in the dataset, but that is not what I want.
I tried;
filter <- filter(dataset, Type == "Green")

but then I get the message

"Error: object 'Type' not found"


dplyr::filter(dataset, Type == "Green") works as expected. Don't save it as filter though. What output do you want?

When the export is being done with R, the CSV has only values from type "Green".

Here's a few ways to filter in R:
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(Hours = c(8, 6), Type = c("Green", "Red"))

green_df1 <- df %>% filter(Type == "Green")

green_df2 <- subset(df, Type == "Green")

green_df3 <- df[df$Type == "Green", ]

write.csv(green_df1, "test.csv", row.names = FALSE)

green_df1 is using the dplyr package, which is useful for stringing together multiple changes to a dataframe in one go.
green_df2 is using a base R version of the filter function.
green_df3 is using the [row, col] format that dataframes use in R to index specific rows where a condition is met.
